# Create a shortcode that creates a form for users to edit their information

Tags: shortcode, users, front-end

I want to make it so that logged in users can edit their information on a page in my site, so that I can avoid having them go to the admin side all together.

I was thinking that I could create a shortcode (in functions.php) that would create the correct table and insert it into the page. I am just starting out with PHP/WordPress so I'm not sure if this is the right path to follow - are there any good resources out there to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very Stack is a great [source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bfrontend+%2Bprofile) of [information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end+profiles).

It'd be a matter of adapting a [good answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end) and making a [shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/51840/12615) out of it.

For this case, it is better to create your [own plugin](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/), see: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615). So you can swap themes and your shortcode will keep working.

Comment: Those resources were exactly what I was looking for - thank you!